# Template id Not working after moving Oscar package to my Application?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-oscar

I am getting 404 error on my home page, I just move Django Oscar package to my application, but it's not working now, Before moving top my application it was wing good, Please let me know what is the issue.
Whenever i am opening my website it's showing me error 404, I think there are some mistake in my urls.py file
Here are my settings.py file...

```
"""
Django settings for frobshop project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.23.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from oscar.defaults import *
location = lambda x: 
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '..', x)
PROJECT_DIR=os.path.dirname(__file__)
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = 
os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

SECRET_KEY = 'bg-a-t#7--wbz$rie*2n%1c-9j#0v8own&5+t7^kduqzc&j5nm'
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.flatpages',
'compressor',
'widget_tweaks',
'haystack',
'treebeard',
'sorl.thumbnail',
'django_tables2',
#'south',
#oscar apps
'oscar',
'oscar.apps.analytics',
'oscar.apps.checkout',
'oscar.apps.address',
'oscar.apps.shipping',
'oscar.apps.catalogue',
'oscar.apps.catalogue.reviews',
'oscar.apps.partner',
'oscar.apps.basket',
'oscar.apps.payment',
'oscar.apps.offer',
'oscar.apps.order',
'oscar.apps.customer',
'oscar.apps.search',
'oscar.apps.voucher',
'oscar.apps.wishlists',
'oscar.apps.dashboard',
'oscar.apps.dashboard.reports',
'oscar.apps.dashboard.users',
'oscar.apps.dashboard.orders',
'oscar.apps.dashboard.catalogue',
'oscar.apps.dashboard.offers',
'oscar.apps.dashboard.partners',
'oscar.apps.dashboard.pages',
'oscar.apps.dashboard.ranges',
'oscar.apps.dashboard.reviews',
'oscar.apps.dashboard.vouchers',
'oscar.apps.dashboard.communications',
'oscar.apps.dashboard.shipping',

 ] 

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'oscar.apps.basket.middleware.BasketMiddleware',
'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
 ]
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'oscar.apps.customer.auth_backends.EmailBackend',
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
 )
EMAIL_BACKEND= 'django.core.mail.backends.console.Emailbackend'

ROOT_URLCONF = 'oscar.urls'

# from oscar import OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR
TEMPLATES = [
{
'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
'DIRS': [
        location('templates'), # templates directory of the 
project
    ],
'APP_DIRS': True,
'OPTIONS': {
'context_processors': [
'django.template.context_processors.debug',
'django.template.context_processors.request',
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
],
},
},
]

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.simple_backend.SimpleEngine',
},
}


TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
 "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
 "django.core.context_processors.request",
 "django.core.context_processors.debug",
 "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
 "django.core.context_processors.media",
 "django.core.context_processors.static",
 "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
 'oscar.apps.search.context_processors.search_form',
 # 'oscar.apps.promotions.context_processors.promotions',
 'oscar.apps.checkout.context_processors.checkout',
 'oscar.apps.customer.notifications.context_processors.
  notifications',
 'oscar.core.context_processors.metadata',
   )
 TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
 WSGI_APPLICATION = 'frobshop.wsgi.application'

 DATABASES = {
 'default': {
 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
 'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
 }
 }

 HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
 'default': {
 'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.simple_backend.SimpleEngine',
  },
  }
```

Here are my app urls.py file..

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url, include

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: show us the full 404 debug trace

Comment: This is complete error...
`Using the URLconf defined in oscar.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^i18n/
^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
The empty path didn't match any of these.`

Comment: @msginfosys which is your home page url? is it `http://ocalhost:8000/ ' ?